# My xhost safest config

Tags: xorg

On my Ubuntu 22.04.2...

I have made some mods and now when i type xhost, system returns:

access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect

LOCAL:

is it safer than?

access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect

SI:localuser:myuser

Former avoids network access, ok??? So, for me it is safer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first one is safer because in the second one it allow access to any client running on the same machine using the specified user
But with the first one you only allow access to only local clients  which limit the security risk/vulnerabilities

Comment: In the second one, SI:localuser:myuser, if i start a xclient with network access, i think it can be considered a security issue in this context exposing other xclients throught lan/net, because X11 do not have gui isolation like wayland ... would be even better if we have this: LOCAL:myuser

Comment: Answer your question with explanation if you think you have a better answer